# Coletar dados do banco do wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Tem como fazer conexão no banco de dados do Wordpress, e pegar os dados de algumas tabelas dele e transferir em um Site ?

Comment: Claro que tem, é uma base de dados comum, se você tiver acesso, claro. Sua pergunta é muito superficial, tente detalhar mais.

Comment: Se explicasse detalhes, podia formular uma resposta. Tente não fazer perguntas assim pouco explicadas, é mais fácil responder e a pergunta tem muito menos chance de ser fechada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem... Tem sim. Basta conhecer o schema do banco de dados do WP. Como o amigo disse ali no comentário, é uma base de dados MySQL comum, então é só conectar e fazer a query de que você precisa.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Neste link você encontra o DER do WP. Dá uma estudada nele e veja que dados você vai precisar recuperar de lá :)

Comment: Só vou fazer a conexão em meu site, e fazer uma select das últimas novidades cadastradas lá no WP. Muito obrigado a vocês!!!!! Irei testar as dicas aqui, e logo eu volto para dar um feedback! Obrigado!